# Sequelize js how to use database functions with a model

Tags: sequelize.js

my use case is something like this,

1. Users can review the dishes.
2. Each review is stored in a table called **ratings**.
3. When a new record inserted to the **ratings table**, **Dish tables** overall rating column should be updated with the average rating value.

I go though the docs and some questions in the stack-overflow and GitHub also.
What I have done so far is.

```js
const db = require("../models");
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

export async function create(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const body = req.swagger.params.body.value;
        const rate = await db.ratings.create(body, {
            fields: ['user_id', 'dish', 'overall', 'notes', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt']
        })

        const average = await Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('overall'))
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json(error)
    }
}
```

I think average function is

> Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('overall'))

But I don't know how to call it on the **model ratings**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can use with `attributes` :

```
db.ratings.findAll({
    attributes : [ [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('overall')),'overall'] ] // <--- All you need is this
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

For more detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html)**

Comment: First things first, thanks a lot for continuously helping me to improve. =) I have changed my query to this const average = await db.ratings.findAll({
            where:{
                dish:1
            },
            attributes: [sequelize.fn('AVG', sequelize.col('overall'))]
        })

then the executed query was this
SELECT AVG(`overall`) FROM `ratings` AS `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`dish` = 1;

But I haven't get anyoutput. I got only an empty object. But I copy the excuted query and run on the
phpmyadmin then query excuted and gives me the output.

Comment: What could went wrong here? "findAll" will gives all the columns and pass the "attributes" will provide
only mentioned columns. So I didn't mention any column is it the reason here?

Comment: @PathumSamararathna , have updated the answer , please try that one